# When function with JPA, Not working

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, jpql

I am trying to use a function with JPA. But I have found the strange thing.
Below code is for testing

```
    List<Order> list = em.createQuery("select o from Order o where function('order_status', o.id) = :status")
            .setParameter("status", status.name())
            .setFirstResult(pageable.getOffset())
            .setMaxResults(pageable.getOffset() + pageable.getPageNumber())
            .getResultList();
    long count = ((BigInteger) em.createQuery("select count(o) from Order o where function('order_status', o.id) = :status")
            .setParameter("status", status.name())
            .getSingleResult()).longValue();
    return new PageImpl(list, pageable, count);
```

The result is

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [ORDER] did not match expected type [java.lang.Long (n/a)]
>       at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:54)
>       at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:27)
>       at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.validate(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:90)
>       at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.setBindValue(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:55)
>       at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:486)
>       at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:104)
>       at com.modatool.core.repository.OrderRepositoryImpl.findByStatus(OrderRepositoryImpl.java:108)

But if :status is not a binding variable, it's working well.

```
        List<Order> list = em.createQuery("select o from Order o where function('order_status', o.id) = 'WAITING'")
//                .setParameter("status", status.name())
                .setFirstResult(pageable.getOffset())
                .setMaxResults(pageable.getOffset() + pageable.getPageNumber())
                .getResultList();
        long count = ((Long) em.createQuery("select count(o) from Order o where function('order_status', o.id) = 'WAITING'")
//                .setParameter("status", status.name())
                .getSingleResult()).longValue();
        return new PageImpl(list, pageable, count);
```

The hibernate version that i am using is 5.2.12.Final. someone, let me know why this happens please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "select o from Order o where function('order_status', o.id) = '" + status.name() + "'" is working, but not a solution. I want to know why. Is this a bug??

Comment: The JPQL is valid. Bug in your JPA provider apparently, so report it

Comment: I made a this problem. I set function configuration in custom dialect class. But it was wrong return type. After edited it, it works.